# Why is the bold text true??

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Ok I have stared at this for nearly 30 minutes now, and can't figure out why the bold text is true.

*Problem:*
If $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathrm{Re}(z^n) \ge 0$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, show that $z \in \mathbb{R}^{\ge 0}.$

*Solution:* $$\mathrm{Re}(z^n) \ge 0 \iff \mathrm{Re}(z^n)=\mathrm{Re}[r^n \mathrm{cis}(n\theta)]=\mathrm{Re}[r^n(\cos n\theta + i \sin n \theta)]=r^n \cos n\theta \geq 0.$$ If $z=0$, we are done since $r=0$ and $\mathrm{Re}(z^n)=0.$ So assume $z \ne 0;$ then $r>0.$ Thus $r^n \cos n\theta \geq 0 \implies (\cos n\theta \geq 0) \ (\forall \ n \in \mathbb{N}).$

The problem is therefore to prove that if $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $0 < \theta \leq 2\pi$, and $\cos(n\theta) \geq 0$ for every positive integer $n,$ then $\theta = 0.$

Suppose that $0 < \theta \leq 2\pi$, and assume that $\cos(n\theta) \geq 0$ for every positive integer $n.$ In particular, $n = 1 \implies \cos(\theta) > 0,$ and so upon requiring that $0 < \theta \leq 2\pi,$ we find that either $0 < \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\frac{3\pi}{2} < \theta \leq 2\pi.$

Consider the possibility that $0 < \cos(\theta) \leq \frac{\pi}{2}.$ There is a positive integer $n$ such that $n\theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ but $(n+1)\theta > \frac{\pi}{2}.$ So $\theta + n\theta > \frac{\pi}{2},$ while $n\theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2},$ and so:
$$(n+1)\theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2} + \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2n} \leq \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2} = \pi.$$
**But then $\cos(\theta) < 0,$ which is not the case.** Thus if $\theta \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}],$ then $\theta = 0,$ and so $z \in \mathbb{R}.$

Now suppose that $\theta \in [\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi).$ Since $\cos(\theta) = \cos(\theta - 2\pi)$, and for every integer $n,$ $$\cos(n\theta) = (\cos(\theta))^n = (\cos(\theta - 2\pi))^n = \cos(n(\theta - 2\pi)),$$ we may assume without loss of
generality that $\theta \in [-\frac{\pi}{2},0].$ Since the cosine function is even, $\cos(n\theta) = \cos(-n\theta) = \cos(n(-\theta))$ for every integer $n.$ Since $0 \le -\theta \le \frac{\pi}{2},$ if $-\theta \neq 0,$ there exists $n$ such that $\cos(n\theta) < 0,$ giving a contradiction.
Thus $\theta = 0.$

Comment: The bold text should be $\cos(n+1)\theta < 0$ (because $\pi/2 < (n+1)\theta < \pi$) and this is a contradiction to the fact that $\cos (m \theta)>0$ for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: There is another typo as well a few lines before the bolded text, "Consider the possibility that $0<\theta\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$" as opposed to $0<\cos(\theta)\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$